# Is this recent question about job post semantics on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

The question in question: [How are salaries listed in Brazil?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/2991/112)

If I understand it correctly, it asks whether a listed salary (using the word *salário*) in Brazil is normally understood to mean a monthly, yearly, weekly, or daily salary. There has been some discussion over whether or not this is on-topic on this site. Is it truly a question about Portuguese?

Clearly, Portuguese is used on the job posting, because it was written in Brazilian Portuguese. According to [the Help Center](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "dialect differences" and "The meaning of a word or expression in context (if it is not clear from the dictionary definition)" are on-topic, and "Anything not directly related to the Portuguese language" is off-topic. This does seem to be a question about the meaning of *salário* in context.

There is still some doubt as to whether this is **directly** related to the Portuguese language. Imagine if the job posting were written in English, and used the word *salary*. If the answer to the question would be the same, because it's the **concept** of a salary—not the **word** *salário*—that is understood to mean "yearly salary" in some places and "monthly salary" in others, then maybe this shouldn't be on-topic here? (In other words, can we ask questions about semantics in Portuguese-speaking regions that go beyond the Portuguese language itself here?) In that case, it might be a better question for another site. Maybe the [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) or [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange sites? (Warning: I don't know if those communities would welcome the question. Expatriates in particular might not.)

So which is it: on-topic or not? And is there a more general principle we can use to determine if questions like this are on-topic here?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the question expects an answer coming from the *Portuguese language*, but in reality, the answer would come more from the *country's work laws and/or culture*. In Brazil, the payment can be monthly, fortnightly, or weekly (but almost always it's monthly), but this isn't because the word "salary" means "to receive money for a work done per month/fortnight/week".

According to the Michaelis Dictionary, the payment is done ["mainly per day and per hour"](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=sal%E1rio), as the definition of "salary":

> **salário**
>   sa.lá.rio
>   sm (lat salariu) **1** Estipêndio ou remuneração por um serviço prestado, principalmente por dia e por hora;

The [Priberam dictionary](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sal%C3%A1rio) says that "salário" can be a "jornal" (daily payment). And the [Aulete dictionary](http://www.aulete.com.br/sal%C3%A1rio) just says that it's a "reward for a work done".

So if one would consider the definition of the word "salary" when a job offer says that the salary is R$ 1500,00, this person would erroneously think that this salary is per day, which is not. To know the payment frequency, this person would have to know in what frequency Brazilians are used to receive the payment or to pay, in which in case the standard is monthly.

So no, this question isn't on topic, because it's about culture/law, not the Portuguese language.

Comment: I am the one who originally asked the question. In fact, I really like this answer. I do note that I am not asking about the law or custom, but the common usage. There is a clear distinction between legal language and common language. My question is strictly focused as described, but on the common usage (as per a job listing), not the legal one (as per government and employment records, census, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Não me parece. O que está em causa não é o significado de *salário*. Todas estas frases são válidas em português:

> - Não longe dali havia uma fábrica da Sanyo, que os congressistas visitaram sem se fazer anunciar e onde viram crianças ocupadas na montagem de sofisticados equipamentos electrónicos, para consumidores americanos com um **salário de 50 dólares (cerca de 8500 escudos) semanais**.
> - Será que um **salário de mais ou menos 150 mil escudos mensais** não é suficiente para eles ?
> - Edmilson tem no Paris Saint-Germain um **salário anual de 950 mil dólares** (cerca de 170 mil contos) , o que neste momento ninguém ganha no plantel portista.

A palavra **salário** não tem nada em si 1) que diga respeito ao valor da remuneração e 2) à frequência com que é pago. Significa tão-só *retribuição pecuniária do serviço executado* (Priberam). Podemos juntar-lhe um complemento, introduzido por *de* ou *no valor de*, a indicar o valor dessa remuneração, mas não há qualquer restrição em relação ao período temporal.

Agora, este período temporal pode claramente ser omitido, e cada país tem convenções diferentes. Em Portugal, o mais comum é citar o valor mensal (que é pago 14 vezes), noutros países à hora, ao ano ou à semana. Portanto a pegunta é na verdade esta:

> No Brasil, qual a base mais comum para citar o valor de uma remuneração salarial?

Agora, é verdade que entender o significado de uma frase implica por vezes conhecer alguns elementos culturais. Se *salário* representasse um conceito que, para ser compreendido, precisasse de algum tipo de contexto cultural, a situação seria outra. Por exemplo, o contexto dado nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2955/how-is-hue-hue-actually-pronounced-in-brazilian-portuguese) é útil. Mas não estamos perante o pedido de informação que ajude a compreender qualquer conceito linguístico.

Parece-me que esta pergunta seria tão *on-topic* como:

> Em quantas vezes são pagos os salários no Brasil?
>   Os salários no Brasil são pagos mensalmente?
>   O valor das remunerações salariais são no Brasil citados brutos ou líquidos de impostos?

e por aí em diante.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, the question is on-topic.

If a question `How is <coiso> understood in <country>?` is on-topic,
so must its counter-point `How should I understand <coiso> in <country>?` be on-topic.

And this question can be distilled to `How should I understand "salary of R$ 2.000,00", in Brazil?`.

## But its quality is *bleh*

That said, the question itself is in dire need of improvement, and in its current shape I don't find it useful for the community.

Comment: Esta regra é demasiado inclusiva. Por exemplo eu posso perguntar, «o que significa responsabilidade civil extracontratual no Brasil?», sabendo o que em geral o que significa «responsabiliade civil extracontratual», mas querendo saber um detalhe específico ao sistema legal brasileiro. O que para mim é uma situação análoga.

Comment: Percebo, @Artefacto, mas não concordo. E não acho que seja análoga: (1) Saberias o que está escrito, só não compreenderias as nuances do seu significado... enquanto que o perguntador compreende as nuances de todos os significados possíveis, mas não sabe o que está [implicitamente] escrito, qual dos significados. (2) Ele simplesmente não consegue deduzir a parte implícita da frase, porque tem uma barreira cultural que lhe é intransponível. (3) Logo: parece-me um problema de leitura, e acho que esses são _on-topic_.

Comment: Mas se calhar estavas a pôr reservas à frase em si e não à minha posição? Aos fundamentos e não à conclusão? Se for esse o caso, tenho de clarificar e melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Não, era aos fundamentos. Quanto aos teus novos argumentos: 1) a distinção que fazes entre saber os significados possíveis, mas não conseguir escolher entre eles e não saber de todo os singificados possíveis não me parece que faça sentido, não vejo por que há de isso alterar a análise. 2) há muito tipo de informação que, a nos faltar, nos pode levar a não compreender uma frase -- estás a dizer que há uma diferença substancial entre ser um dado sobre práticas no mercado laboral brasileiro e uma dado geral sobre direito civil?

Comment: Bom, então tenho de rever e solidificar isto. Obrigado pelas críticas. :) (2) Sim, estou, @Artefacto. Acho que este caso está mais perto de "o que significa cu no Brasil" do que de "o que significa responsabilidade civil extracontratual no Brasil".